# Designing Parking Floor for O(1) Access to different Space Types

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I recently was going through the canonical example of designing a parking lot system using OOD principles. One thing I was thinking about was being able to quickly access if a floor has the proper parking spot type for a particular Vehicle.

```
public class ParkingFloor {
    Map<ParkingSpotType, Stack<ParkingSpot>> spotTypeToSpots;

    public ParkingFloor() {
        this.spotTypeToSpots = new HashMap<>();
    }


    public ParkingSpot getSpaceForSpotType(ParkingSpotType type) {
        if (!spotTypeToSpots.get(type).isEmpty()) {
            spotTypeToSpots.get(type).pop();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addSpotToMap(ParkingSpot spot) {
        this.spotTypeToSpots.computeIfAbsent(spot.getType(), t -> new Stack<>()).add(spot);
    }
}

public interface ParkingSpot {
    boolean isOccupied();

    ParkingSpotType getType();
}

public class CompactSpot {
    ParkingSpotType parkingSpotType;
    boolean isOccupied;
    public CompactSpot() {
        this.isOccupied = false;
        this.parkingSpotType = ParkingSpotType.COMPACT;
    }
}
public enum ParkingSpotType {
    MOTORCYCLE, SUV, COMPACT
}
```

In my example I'm assigning each subclass of parking spot a enum type and then using that to key the map. It feels a little awkward to be performing the check in this way though, since the subclass inherently is a different "type". Could I just be using getClass() here, and is that a common practice? Is there maybe a better way to implement something like this?

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question: it doesn't really describe the question you are asking. I'd suggest "should I use getClass() instead of an enum attribute to represent the 'type' of an object in a map?" My answer is a very firm 'no' - using reflection should be a rare use case. You might want to consider not subclassing parking spots to represent different types. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance for more details.

Comment: I think that depends on whether your packing slot subtype would have distinctive behavior. One thing interface inheritance provides you is you can define its own behavior/method in the class. Would a SUV parking slot act very differently than a motorcycle parking slot? That is up to your problems domain of your application.